# How to empty swap if there is free RAM?

Tags: performance, swap, ram-usage

When I open a RAM-intensive app (VirtualBox set at 2GB of RAM), some swap space is generally used, depending on what else I have open at the time.

However, when I quit that last application, the 2GB of RAM is freed up, but the same swap space use remains.

For example, right now, about two hours after having closed VirtualBox, I have 1.6GB free RAM and still 770MB in swap.

How can I tell Ubuntu to stop using that swap and to revert to using the RAM?

Comment: The easiest thing **reboot your device** and save time of coping to ram and free ram save power of laptop and cpu temperature

Comment: Big assumption that repopulating all the stuff on your computer takes less time than that.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, at least, can keep using swap long after it was needed thusly making your system orders of magnitude slower by relying on the swap file even though no longer a necessity. The manual intervention can therefore by useful. Rebooting is not always an option.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Just because swap is allocated, doesn't mean it's being 'used'. Whilst programs like system monitor and top will show some of your swap space being allocated (in your example 770MB) that doesn't mean that the system is actively swapping in/out.

To find out if anything is swapping in/out you can use the `vmstat` command. Leave it running a few seconds to settle down and watch the `si` (swapin) and `so` (swapout) columns. If nothing is happening then there is no reason to be concerned.

Here's the output of running `vmstat 1`, where you can see my machine is not swapping at all.

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0  78588 230788   9596  72196    0    0     0     0  543  652 12  6 78  0
 0  0  78588 230780   9596  72196    0    0     0     0  531  410  1  0 99  0
 0  0  78588 230796   9596  72196    0    0     0     0  300  335  1  1 97  0
 1  0  78588 230788   9608  72224    0    0    40     0  737  762  4  4 84  8
 5  0  78588 230788   9608  72224    0    0     0     0  415  385  9  3 84  0
 0  0  78588 230540   9616  72224    0    0     0    44  611  556 55  5 31  0
 0  0  78588 230532   9616  72224    0    0     0     0  574  662  1  6 89  0
```

Yet here in `top` you can see I have swap space allocated:-

```
Mem:    475236k total,   245076k used,   230160k free,     9720k buffers
Swap:   491512k total,    78588k used,   412924k free,    72476k cached
```

Comment: “no reason to be concerned”, up to the point when I continue to use some application that was swapped out. then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The premise of the question is based on misconceptions. This post addresses the misconceptions.

Comment: I don't see a misconception, I see a disagreement about what "used" means. You are meaning "used" to refer to actively swapping in/out, while the original question appears to be posed with "used" meaning that there is data that has been swapped out, which may later need to be swapped back in. There are valid reasons to want to flush the swap after an event that swaps out a lot of other memory, essentially pre-empting the active swapping that the user knows will occur later (especially if the later 'de-swapping' is likely to occur while the disk is under load for other reasons).

Comment: After running a memory intensive application, my other applications are unrepsonsive when I switch to them, presumably due to being swapped.  Some way of telling the system to un-swap as much data as possible (followed by a coffee break) would be better than having to wait 20s every time I Alt+Tab.

Comment: I tried `vmstat` and `si` & `so` where idle. Then I tried `swapoff`. This time, I can see the swap is getting reduced and the main memory is getting allocated.

Comment: The title of the question is specifically asking about emptying swap.  For example, the Oracle installer won't run some (any) commands if there is less than 500 MB of swap available, it doesn't matter if there is 200+GB of free RAM.  Whether the swap is being actively used, something is using it by sitting there.  In most cases inactive swap use *might* make it slow to switch tasks, while other cases it breaks functionality.

Comment: This does not answer the question!

Comment: This is also useless for times when your swap has useless data inside it. I once used the swapoff swapon trick on a 2GB swap and it only took 500MB while it was active in the memory.

Comment: I have done this but now htop says there are 0k/0k of swap used, like if the swap is not available anymore...

Comment: "If nothing is happening then there is no reason to be concerned.", I find this hard to believe. I had memory intensive calculations force the use of swap, after killing the calculations and having a surplus of RAM again, swap stayed filled and firefox was responding slow. Killing firefox emptied a lot of swap, after restaring firefox was fast again. I expect that the OS doesn't always operate efficiently regarding swap.

Comment: @emchristiansen It does better than answer, but gives some insight into the inner workings of the kernel and paging.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The application I am working with will crash unless a certain amount of swap is available when I start it. It does not matter that Linux is not swapping in/out.

Answer (score 699):

The Linux kernel underlying Ubuntu will automatically "swap in" those pages from disk to RAM as needed, so in general I'd say just let it happen naturally.

However, if you really feel that you need to force it, (I can see a scenario where you would want to know the system will be responsive later) you can momentarily disable and re-enable swap

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo swapon -a
```

OR alternatively as a single line

```
sudo swapoff -a; sudo swapon -a
```

Be careful doing this, as you may make your system unstable, especially if its already low on RAM. Be sure to have enough free RAM in your system, or you might not be able to free the swap and the OOM-Killer would end up killing some of your processes.

Note that the `swapoff` may take a while. This is particularly true if you have lot of swap to be swapped off.

Comment: That did the trick, the swap was copied to ram. I guess you just need to make sure to have at least the amount of swap used as free ram before running swapoff, right?

Comment: The swap was not copied to RAM. It was merely disabled. You should ensure the box is not swapping before doing this. If you do, then the kernel will see the memory disappear and the OOM-Killer will probably start killing off applications arbitrarily. There's no reason you should need to 'clean' out the swap like this. (see my other comment) :)

Comment: Actually the swap is, basically, copied to ram, or more accurately, the pages are swapped back in from disk to RAM before the swap can be disabled.

Comment: The pages are copied to RAM only if they are still needed by some process. Sometimes a swapped page belongs to a process that has already been finished, and the kernel doesn't care to remove these pages from swap immediately.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it is the way to get the swapped pages back to RAM and then empty the swap memory

Comment: This is the single answer that actually answers the question, and should be the accepted one!

Comment: You can view the progress (to get a rough idea of how long it will take) using `watch free -h`, the total swap and used swap will go down as it's being moved.

Comment: This indeed does the job. But it is not worth it in my case: I swapped 4Gb into mem and it took 3 min: first 2.5 min nothing happened and the swap was only swapped in the last 30 seconds.

Comment: I actually made myself a shell script that does just this and put to /usr/bin/reswap. Now I can do this with one command.

Comment: I am looking at creating a Nagios alert that warns us when a system has started to swap. For example, at this moment I have a system with 8/16G swap used, but only 36/128G RAM in use. If Nagios is alerting, I'd like to clear the swap so it quiets down. I know the swap isn't being used at this moment, but Nagios doesn't. So here's one use case where being able to "flush" the swap space would be handy... as simply a bookkeeping exercise.

Comment: @jfoucher I think you should mark this answer as the correct answer, given that it actually answers the specific question that you asked. The current correct answer, deals more with explaining the working of swap out and swap in rather than how to clean out the swap and move it to memory. Also, see Scott Severance's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/90399/59090) for a script to do the same thing.

Comment: `swapoff`: `-a, --all              disable all swaps from /proc/swaps`
           .................. .................. .................. 
`swapon`: `-a, --all                enable all swaps from /etc/fstab` (if you are using e.g. manual swap file, you have to add it yourself again, swapon -a won't do it :) )

Comment: in my experience swapoff may take a very looooooong time to complete draining the swap file back to RAM. not sure why.

Comment: I don't actually experience this happening
> "The Linux kernel underlying Ubuntu will automatically "swap in" those pages from disk to RAM as needed"

Comment: IMHO one should *not* use `&&` but rather a semicolon (`swapoff -a; swapon -a`) instead! Why? Suppose you're having *multiple* swap devices. `swapoff` then might succeed on one device, but fail on the other. In such a case, the `swapoff` command will return a non-zero exit code, causing the `swapon -a` command not to be executed, hence ending up with *less* swap space than before!

Comment: Is there a way to do this for single processes? They could be stopped, everything moved to RAM and then continued...

Comment: I was expecting swap to be moved to RAM quickly, but in fact there is no "transfer". It just disable swap, and swap is emptying as long as applications free memory. So it can take few minutes. But I could stop it with ctrl+C: swap just enables back with the rest of data.

Comment: @Shelvacu btw another way to watch the progress - with GUI - (e.g. if you're on Ubuntu) is the embedded System Monitor which shows swap usage.

Comment: @matt i confirm that it's very slow, but you haven't say HOW MUCH slow it is (this may be interesting to someone). in my case it's about 1 MB per second. e.g. if i have 8 gb ram & 8 gb swap and my swap is 15% used then it'll take approx. 20 minutes to free it! that's loooooong. all that time, one of my cpu cores is 100% busy. i have 4 cores -> cpu is 25% busy. maybe this info will be helpful for someone who's deciding whether should they try it

Comment: Life just got so much better with this level-up command! No more need to reboot my Debian. Every Linux user should know these commands.

Comment: Depending on how long it takes to move everything out of swap, it might be better to run `sudo bash -c "swapoff -a; swapon -a"` to avoid off chance that you might have to enter your password twice.

Comment: Is it safe, doing this on a live system, e.g. with a DB? Would it noticeable slow down everything while swapoff/swapon is running?

Comment: is `sudo swapoff -a` going to keep in disabled forever? I don't care about swap because I have 64GB or RAM and it only makes things slowdown.

Answer (score 183):

You can also set your "swappiness" value from the default of 60, this way the swap won't grow so large to begin with. Why the shipping default is set to 60 when the recommended value is 10 perplexes me. [From the Ubuntu SwapFAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F):

> The default setting in Ubuntu is swappiness=60. **Reducing the default value of swappiness will probably improve overall performance for a typical Ubuntu desktop installation. A value of swappiness=10 is recommended**, but feel free to experiment.

By changing this value to 10 or even 0, you can add a significant and perceivable speed boost to an older system with a slow drive. Setting this value to 0 does not turn swap off for Linux kernel 3.4 and below but with 3.5+ it does so you will want to use a value of 1 if you want to keep it on its lowest setting*.

I see no reason not to set this to 0 since anything that hits disk is slower than RAM. I have 8 virtual cores, a fast SSD & 8 GB of memory and my swap is set to 0. As of this moment I have 3 virtual machines running, my memory usage is 7.1 of 7.7 GB, my used swap is only at 576KB of 952MB and all systems are running smoothly!

[From the Ubuntu SwapFAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F):

> The swappiness parameter controls the tendency of the kernel to move processes out of physical memory and onto the swap disk. Because disks are much slower than RAM, this can lead to slower response times for system and applications if processes are too aggressively moved out of memory.
>
> 1. swappiness can have a value of between 0 and 100
> 2. swappiness=0 tells the kernel to avoid swapping processes out of physical memory for as long as possible
> 3. swappiness=100 tells the kernel to aggressively swap processes out of physical memory and move them to swap cache

**Below are basic instructions for checking swappiness, emptying your swap and changing the swappiness to 0:**

To check the swappiness value:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

To temporarily set swap to 0 ([as suggested by SpamapS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357/how-to-empty-swap-if-there-is-free-ram/1359#1359)):

*This will empty your swap and transfer all the swap back into memory. First make sure you have enough memory available by viewing the resources tab of gnome-system-monitor, your free memory should be greater than your used swap. This process may take a while, use gnome-system-monitor to monitor and verify the progress.*

```
sudo swapoff --all
```

To set the new value to 0:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0
```

To turn swap back on:

```
sudo swapon --all
```

To permanently set swappiness to 0:

1. `sudoedit /etc/sysctl.conf`
2. Add this line `vm.swappiness = 0`
3. `sudo shutdown -r now` # restart system

* With kernel version 3.5+ setting swappiness to 0 does turn it off entirely and a setting of 1 is recommended if you want the lowest swappiness algorithm. source: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/04/28/oom-relation-vm-swappiness0-new-kernel/

Comment: I just updated the answer to include a permanent way to set swappiness. Not sure how it got upvoted so much, I am guessing nobody tested it.

Comment: More good reading on swappiness in this answer => http://askubuntu.com/a/103916/11929

Comment: Added a note about the behavior of swappiness=0 changing with Linux kernel version 3.5+.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this good answer. I suggest, as you said in the last lines (with *), to modify accordingly also your entire answer (that means set swappiness to 1 as preferred, not 0). This would make the answer more consistent, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was available when the author originally posted the answer but a swappiness value of "60" is in place for ubuntu server installs since that environment has a different set of specifications for performance.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F

Comment: why do you have swap in the first place when you then set the swappiness to 0? If you really want to disable swap I'd prefer to grab back that disk space ^^

Comment: Because there is no way to turn swapiness off in 3.4 and lower kernels, the only way is to set swapiness to 0, in 3.5 and later swapiness 0 this is how you disable it.

Comment: This setting is very effective in controlling the size of the swap. My system has 16G RAM and 16G swap. Sometimes I'm running to VMs and some of my applications get swapped out. When I close the VMs the RAM usage drops, but the swap usage remains the same and my system lags when changing applications. Changing the swapiness has improved performance for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer really. Thorough explanation of the problem, and it's solution, as well as links and a solution to retain Swap memory, but help keep it under control in the first place. Awesome stuff. Thanks. :)

Comment: Is the 3.5+ still true? I have Kernel 4.15 with swappiness 0, swap still works (but only when really needed)

Comment: I actually have the best results (regarding responsivity and swap times) using a swappiness value of 70 or even 80 (Arch Linux, kernel 5.3). Yes, using a lower swappiness value makes the kernel swap memory less often, but when it does... Good luck waiting up to 5 minutes until getting control of your mouse cursor back.

Answer (score 61):

I've found that emptying swap can help a lot on systems with slow disks and limited RAM. Of course, as already mentioned, the way to do this is to run `sudo swapoff -a; sudo swapon -a`. The problem here is that if there's insufficient RAM, doing so will cause all sorts of problems.

I've written a script that I call `toggle_swap` that has worked for me for the last several years. It checks for enough free RAM before actually disabling the swap. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

free_data="$(free)"
mem_data="$(echo "$free_data" | grep 'Mem:')"
free_mem="$(echo "$mem_data" | awk '{print $4}')"
buffers="$(echo "$mem_data" | awk '{print $6}')"
cache="$(echo "$mem_data" | awk '{print $7}')"
total_free=$((free_mem + buffers + cache))
used_swap="$(echo "$free_data" | grep 'Swap:' | awk '{print $3}')"

echo -e "Free memory:\t$total_free kB ($((total_free / 1024)) MB)\nUsed swap:\t$used_swap kB ($((used_swap / 1024)) MB)"
if [[ $used_swap -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Congratulations! No swap is in use."
elif [[ $used_swap -lt $total_free ]]; then
    echo "Freeing swap..."
    sudo swapoff -a
    sudo swapon -a
else
    echo "Not enough free memory. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Awesome I was looking for something like this. Maybe to be a little safer you could present the number and percentages and then ask, just to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I've update the code and have created a gist based  https://gist.github.com/Jekis/6c8fe9dfb999fa76479058e2d769ee5c

Comment: This is the conclusion I reached after reading all the tips, like one should somehow make sure there is enough RAM indeed before killing swap. Thank you sir, wonderful script. Should be included in Ubuntu by default (not kidding, it really is a musthave.)

Comment: Except that if you run any new thing while turning off swap, and before it's back on - it won't have enough memory.

Comment: That depends on how much free memory you have. If there's enough free memory to hold everything in swap AND the new process, then there's no issue. If not then you're right.

Comment: Does this really work better than just reducing `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` from the default 70 down to 10 or 20?  The kernel will still swap when needed, but is less aggressive about it.  Do you actually find your system getting slow, or do you just like seeing low swap-usage numbers?

Comment: Oh, you're using this manually instead of having everything be slow the first time you use it.  [A recent question](https://askubuntu.com/a/973548/116941) was asking about swapoff/swapon from an hourly cron job, and an answer linked here.  IMO, *that* sounds like a bad idea even if you do check to make sure there's enough memory.  This is a good answer to *this* question, for a manual unswap-everything script.

Comment: I got
```
Freeing swap...
swapoff: /dev/sdb5: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory
swapoff: /dev/sda5: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: Try running `swapoff` and `swapon` manually and see if you get errors that way. If so, that's a separate issue.

Comment: 2023 - Works for a PopOS 22.04  box

Comment: @ScottSeverance Computing *`free_mem + buffers + cache`* result to more than *`total`*!! See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1497801/295207) (Your use of fork to `awk` is *overkill*)

Answer (score 26):

After mucking around with [swappiness](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) for a couple of days, I've come to the conclusion that the kernel should be left to its own devices. It knows what it's doing, and it's optimized to give you the best experience.

Unless you have a really good reason for wanting that disk back, I'd leave it be.

Comment: I had some stuff in swap, vmstat showed me that swapin and swapout was happening, and Chrome was laggy af, while my CPU was barely used. Good enough reason, no?

Comment: There are definitely cases where certain swapping on desktop makes it laggy. (not while it is swapping, but also after, when there is enough RAM, for long time after.) So at best this answer is only subjective experience which happens in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

New anser 2023!

## Some tips and tricks

In addition to all existing answer I want to share some tricks I use.

### Reading `free`'s output

First, ensure that output of `free` is not *localized*, for this you have to prepend command by `LANG=C free -k`:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        32739720     9436264     8704992      883044    15959152    23303456
Swap:       23437308     5450752    17986556
```

Where, if you compute *`buff/cache + available`* the result will be bigger than `total`! This is wrong!!

Just consider if *`available mem` is bigger than `used swap`*, before *purging swap*!

```bash
msgs=("NOT " "")
{ # read `free` output, ignore 1st line and all values but free and swaped.
    read _
    read -r _{,,,,,} avail
    read -r _ _ swaped _
} < <(LANG=C free -k)
printf 'Avail: %d swaped: %d Can %sunswap!\n' \
           "$avail" "$swaped" "${msgs[ avail > swaped ]}"
```

```
 Avail: 23303456 swaped: 5450752 Can unswap!
```

#### Alternative using `/proc/meminfo` instead of `free`

Accessing directly `/proc/meminfo` instead of running a *fork* to `free`, you could obtain same values by:

```bash
msgs=("NOT " "")
while read field val _; do
    case $field in
        MemAvailable: ) avail=$val ;;
        SwapTotal: )    declare -i swaped=$val ;;
        SwapFree: )     swaped+=-$val; break ;;
    esac
done < /proc/meminfo
printf 'Avail: %d swaped: %d Can %sunswap!\n' \
           "$avail" "$swaped" "${msgs[ avail > swaped ]}"
```

```
 Avail: 23303456 swaped: 5450752 Can unswap!
```

### Purging swap `swapoff -a`.

I've build a little script that

- correctly parse `free`'s output,
- show human readable *swaped* and *avail* memory,
- offer to run *`swapoff - swaponn`* loop if user don't interact
- then compute elapsed time used to *`unswap`*.

There is my [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script, based on *`bash V>5.0`*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

msgs=("NOT " "")
while read field val _; do
    case $field in
        MemAvailable: ) avail=$val ;;
        SwapTotal: )    declare -i swaped=$val ;;
        SwapFree: )     swaped+=-$val; break ;;
    esac
done < /proc/meminfo

txtsize() { # Convert integer into readable string, store result in $2 varname
    local i=$(($1>=1<<50?5:$1>=1<<40?4:$1>=1<<30?3:$1>=1<<20?2:$1>1023?1:0))
    local a=(K M G T P)
    ((i>4?i+=-2:0)) && a=(${a[@]:2}) && set -- $(($1>>20)) $2
    local r=00$((1000*$1/(1024**i)))
    printf -v $2 %.2f%s ${r::-3}.${r: -3} ${a[i]}
}

txtsize $avail havail
txtsize $swaped hswaped
printf 'Avail: %s (%d) swaped: (%s) %d Can %sunswap!\n' \
    "$havail" $avail "$hswaped" $swaped "${msgs[ avail > swaped ]}"
```

```bash
if (( avail > swaped )); then
    if read -sn 1 -t 5 -p\
        'Proceed in 5 seconds. Hit any key to stop now. '; then
        echo $'\nUser abort.'
            exit 0
    fi
    echo
    elapsedTime=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    swapoff -a
    elapsedTime=00000$(( ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} - elapsedTime ))
    swapon -a
    elapsedMin=$(( 10#$elapsedTime / 60000000 ))
    elapsedSec=00000$(( 10#$elapsedTime % 60000000 ))
    printf 'Swap: %s purged in %d minutes and %.3f secs (%.4f").\n' \
        "$hswaped" "$elapsedMin" ${elapsedSec::-6}.${elapsedSec: -6} \
        ${elapsedTime::-6}.${elapsedTime: -6}

fi
```

His ouptut look like:

```
Avail: 23.86G (25023596) swaped: (1.14G) 1192460 Can unswap!
Proceed in 5 seconds. Hit any key to stop now. 
Swap: 1.14G purged in 1 minutes and 51.166 secs (111.1661").
```

This script **require *`root`* privilege**. But you could edit them to add `sudo` before `swapoff -a` and `swapon -a`.

From there, as this opereation could take some time, I've built a [Full *purgeSwap* script](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/purgeSwap.sh.txt), showing progression with [a nice progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298090/1765658) and compute end time estimation, you my download here:  [purgeSwap.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/purgeSwap.sh).

This answer is linked to this other one: [How to find out which processes are using swap space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38790442/1765658)

### About `swapiness`

I'm not totally convinced on how this compute percent of used memeory: including swap or not... For my tests, I'v seen swaping a lot before reaching percents configured in this kernel variable.

Anyway, for my servers, I still use:

```
echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

for running system that was not already configured by:

```
echo >/etc/sysctl.d/90-swapiness.conf  'vm.swappiness = 10'
```

before last reboot.

### Use of `vmstat 1`

I often use this, but as I like graphical presentation, I've build (in 2009)
a perl CGI, that could work in *standalone*:

```
http://perso.f-hauri.ch/~felix/marcm/vmstat.cgi
```

This script is *self-downloadable*, work in any web server, but could be used directly on poor systems. Graphics are drawn in svg and rendered by your browser.

Sample of use:

```bash
wget -O vmstat.pl http://perso.f-hauri.ch/~felix/marcm/vmstat.cgi/download/vmstat.cgi
LANG=C perl vmstat.pl
```

```
CGI::Pretty is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future release. Please see https://github.com/leejo/CGI.pm/issues/162 for more information at /usr/share/perl5/CGI/Pretty.pm line 20.
Server started at port 8881
```

Yes, it's an old script **Don't run them as root!!**.

...Then you could connect with a browser:

```
http://ip.add.re.ss:8881/

http://127.0.0.1/?delay=1&width=1800&height=120
```

Here 1'800 dots with a delay of 1 seconds make half hour graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the vm to not be so swappy, by resucing the swappiness, by

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

or even not be swappy as much as possible by

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0
```

Please read the documentation of swapfile here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't affect performance if your swap space is occupied. The only performance penalty is is stuff is going in/out of swap. If nothing is being swapped in/swapped out, then you don't have to worry about anything.

Comment: Yeah but if something _is_ being swapped it _does_ affect performance, hence this question.

Comment: That is some real nonsense, usually big fallback swaps are on HDDs or generally on a slower device than RAM - if space runs out - existing stuff is swapped - like e.g. internet browser - and then you're practically using it from the slower device...

Comment: Memory is usually being swapped way before RAM space is running out. This is controlled by the `vm.swappiness` parameter. As soon as swap space is occupied there will be a performance impact when a memory page is accessed that has been swapped out to disk.