# How to clean SWAP space in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ram, swap

I have a computer with ubuntu 12.04 installed. Unfortunately, when I run a memory taking program, it fills the RAM and uses the SWAP space. Then after the program terminates, the memory is completely released, but a considerable portion of the swap is occupied and I have to restart my computer to release that part.

The program does not have memory leak. Is there any way to clean that swap? Why such thing happens? (I regularly install the updates)

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/1357/71679

Comment: That question is totally different! I have already checked that. It asks why the system is using swap while the RAM is empty; I am asking why the OS does not release the swap after terminating the program!

Comment: swap on swap off is the answer you are looking for which is  in the answers given

Comment: Appreciating your effort to make this web site better, first of all, answer "may be" the same, but the question is totally different and u don't usually look for your answer in another question. Besides, the marked answer to that question is different and you can check it.

Comment: The difference you state does not make any difference. The accepted answer explains why you need not worry, and the next answer tells you how to do it in case you absolutely need to.