# Ubuntu 16.04 use swap instead of ram when it still has a lot of free memory

Tags: 16.04, ram, swap

I already set the `swappiness` by 10 (even reboot). But I always feel it's using swap space instead of ram space (I heard the sound of HDD), and the system sometime freeze. The question is how to check what and why it's using swap space and how to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357/how-to-empty-swap-if-there-is-free-ram

Comment: ya, but I heard the HDD sound and system is freezing, I think it isn't just allocated.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe a hard drive going bad or something?  If you have `smartctl` installed, you can run the following to get all the SMART information for your drives:  `ls /dev/sd? | while read drv; do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl --all $drv | awk '/SMART overall/ {print $NF}'; done`

Comment: Or, in the link I posted here, there is an answer down below that states to maybe set the swappiness to 1.  Maybe that might help keep stuff out of the swap if something is getting into there.

Comment: Leave it alone. Some swap may always be used, even with 8G RAM. Leave vm.swappiness at 10, if you like. Setting it any lower effects disk buffers, and you'll slow down disk access. And the proper command to check the vm.swappiness value is `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Disk noise may be another problem. Open the `Disks` app, select the proper hard disk in the left pane, click on the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data. Run the tests. If that comes out good, then in `terminal` do `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and look for error messages.

Comment: Do you have Intel Bay Trail processors?

Comment: Thank you all, I'm thinking that my disk having problem.